# Freemarker Variable replacement behavior modification

Tags: freemarker

I am working on JSF based application which has to generate different views (1. PDF, 2. Readonly XHTML, 3. XHTML with FORM backed by a JSF backing bean) from a single docx template. This docx template is based on Freemarker variables. The data model for the Freemarker template engine is **DynamicEntity** see http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/org/eclipse/persistence/dynamic/DynamicEntity.html

For generation of XHTML with FORM backed by a JSF backing bean, I want to **mark certain variables** in the docx template as Editable e.g. ${**edit_**customer.name} and during the template engine replacement process instead of trying to replace them with a value from data model, I want to replace them with JSF EL expressions e.g **< h:inputtext value="#{customer.name}" />**. So at the end I would have one docx. template with special markers which would have special meaning for Editable XHTML and have to ignore them for PDF/Readonly-XHTML.

I looked at Freemarker source code to find the hooking point where I can change the variable deplacement behavior but could not find any clue. The things there are declared final and not extensible :(

Does anyone has idea how can achieve the above requirement?

Comment: You say that you want to mark certain variables as editable. As far as I understand, you want to do that in the template (as opposed to in the data-model). So then, why don't you just replace `${customer.name}` with something like `<@my.editable 'customer.name' />`?

Comment: BTW, how variables are resolved should be addressed in the data-model and/or in the `ObjectWrapper` (see `Configuration.setObjectWrapper`). If you really want to do that.

Comment: I cant use directly html input tags in the template because the same template would be used for pdf generation.

Comment: That's true the variable resolution should be done in data model and i am doing this. when Freemarker is replacing a variable for example $cutsomer.address.name, the last resolved variable is "name" and from DynamicEntity data model (which is based on Hashmap) i could not build an expression like #{customer.address.name}.

Comment: `<@my.editable ...>` is not a HTML Tag, it's a FreeMarker directive (or macro) call. As such, it can output whatever you need there.

Comment: As of the data-model thing, it's possible to make an `ObjectWrapper` that will track how the value was accessed ("customer" then "address" then "name"). Surely it's a somewhat more involved work, understanding object wrapping and all that.

Comment: Thank @ddekany. Writing a macro seems good. I want a macro like this    <#macro editable field>
 <#if ${isEditable} == true>
        <h:inputext value="#{${field}}" />
    <#else>
     ${field}
 </#if>
</#macro>. I have few questions: 1).The isEditable variable i want to set via java API call before template processing? 2). In If block  want to print the field variable name? 3). In Else block want to print the value of the field variable name? 4). Last how to import this template automatically in all my templates, where to place this template in java project and how to do an auto import?

Comment: As in `<@my.editable 'customer.name' />` you pass in the expression itself in a string literal rather than the value of the expression, `${field}` will print the expression itself, while `${field?eval}` will print the value of the expression. And probably you want to pass in `isEditable` with the data-model, but if there's another way of detecting this, then do that. The other questions are, I believe, off-topic regarding the original question and can be looked up elsewhere.

Comment: (And the correct way of writing `<#if ${isEditable} == true>` is simply `<#if isEditable>`.)

Comment: This works for single fields. I am looking now how can i do the same for #List. My docx template uses the #List to generate tabular view. First column of the table has [#list Order.orderItemList as item] ${item.itemId} , 2nd column has ${item.description} and so on. In macro IF isEditable=true then want to generate expressions like #{Order.orderItemList[0]},  #{Order.orderItemList[1]} and so on. ELSE print value. I could not figure out how can i achieve this. Any hint?

Comment: Any hint/idea please???

Comment: The same approach should work for that too, only now you will have to write `<@my.editable 'Order.orderItemList[${item_index}]' />`. That kind of kills the point of `#list` (and is horrid from performance standpoint, but let's hope it's still fast enough), but if you can't just populate the data-model with strings like `"#{Order.orderItemList[0]}"`, I don't think you can do any better. Speaking of which... can't you? Then plain `${item}` would work. Same for the single field stuff.

Comment: <@my.editable 'Order.orderItemList[${item_index}]' /> way works. Thanks